# Convertir .bat a .exe en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo una aplicación en [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) que crea un `.bat` que imprime "Hola Mundo". Quiero saber cómo convertir dicho archivo `.bat` a `.exe` desde mi propia aplicación, sin usar otro software.

En caso de que esto no sea posible, como hacer un `.exe` que acepte los comandos que se usan en los `.bat`.

Comment: Hola Marcus, habría que ver que tiene ese bat, pero en general creo que se podrían ejecutar esos comando por consola pero llamando a la consola desde c#, y una vez se compile el proyecto te generará ese .exe que deseas, puesto que generar un .exe, desde un proyecto de C# (osea un .exe) seria más bien redunda cuando el proyecto perse ya seria un .exe, coloca que hace el bat y te ayudo.

Answer (score 0):

No se que utilidad le vas a dar a tu proyecto.pero un programa en c# que cree un .bat y luego lo convierta a .exe, es un poco extraño.

Segun mi poca experiencia un .bat hay paginas que te lo convierten a .exe
http://www.f2ko.de/es/b2e.php

Si lo que quieres es ejecutar desde c# directamente un .bat, seria algo así:
`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\mi_archivo.bat");`

Y por último no entiendo la necesidad del paso intermedio a .bat porque desde c# también podrías ejecutar un .exe

(ps: si esto es para algún tipo de programa que crea algún tipo de virus, el .exe malos resultados te va a dar porque lo detecta cualquier antivirus)

Espero te ayude algo.

Comment: Es posible ejecutar un .exe desde C# con facilidad. Pero Crear un .exe dinámicamente y despues ejecutarlo es difícil; concretamente lo difícil es crearlo dinámicamente. El crear un script dinámicamente y después ejecutarlo es una técnica normal.

Comment: Creo que no me expliqué bien. Mi programa crea un .bat que imprime Hola Mundo. El problema es que cualquiera puede abrir el .bat con el edito de texto y ver el código.
Si intentas abrir un exe con el editor de texto este te muestra caractéres basura en vez del código.
Lo que busco es una forma de convertir el .bat a .exe desde mi propia aplicación, sin usar otro Software.

Comment: quizas deberias replantearte el asunto, y en lugar de crear un bat desde tu programa, haz un programa en C# que haga lo que hace el .bat, y lo compilas. Como tal el codigo del .exe es ejecutable binario. Te va a depender de varias cosas, entre otras la plataforma en la que creas el ejecutable (no es lo mismo un exe de 64bits que uno de 32, no te sirve un ejecutable exe en linux o en mac...)

Answer (score 0):

Checa estos links:

[StackOverflow - Convert BAT to EXE without external tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174386/how-can-a-bat-file-be-converted-to-exe-without-third-party-tools)

[Superuser - How can I convert a batch to a Exe](https://superuser.com/questions/868340/how-can-i-convert-a-windows-batch-script-to-a-exe)

Como referencia:

> Un archivo batch es un archivo de procesamiento por lotes. Se trata de archivos de texto sin formato, guardados con la extensión .BAT que contienen un conjunto de instrucciones MS-DOS. Cuando se ejecuta este archivo, las órdenes contenidas son ejecutadas en grupo, de forma secuencial, permitiendo automatizar diversas tareas. Cualquier orden reconocible por MS-DOS puede ser utilizado en un archivo batch.
>   ...
>   Un tipo batch es un archivo de texto que contiene órdenes a ejecutar en un intérprete de órdenes propio de DOS o OS/2. Cuando es iniciado, un programa shell —típicamente command.com o cmd.exe— lo lee y ejecuta, generalmente línea a línea. De este modo, se emplea para ejecutar series de comandos automáticamente. El hecho de que funcione solo para MS-DOS lo hace muy limitado. Su extensión es .bat o .cmd.
>   Fuente: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo_batch

Por otra parte un archivo EXE se trata de un programa escrito en un [lenguaje de programación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_de_programaci%C3%B3n) "compilado" a [lenguaje máquina](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_de_m%C3%A1quina) es decir en un idioma que el hardware lo entiende.

Te recomendaría escribir en C# el programa que requieres en lugar de usar un batch es generalmente mas sencillo, también puedes mandar llamar un batch desde un EXE como ya publicó @Chema_MM.

Suerte